# Regex filter by tags ignoring the same tags inside

Tags: php, regex

have the following regex to filter some groups of tables  `<table.*?class="ARTabResultados".*?>(.*?)<\/table>` it works fine as long this table doesn't have another table inside of it.

But in one case it have a table inside how can I control that the regex to get the content until the close tag of this table and not the one inside of it

like in this example

```
<table><div><table></table></div></table>
```

where the return value would be `<div><table>` and whant the `<div><table></table></div>`

can't change `(.*?)` to `(.*)` or `(.+)` for would stop fetching the other tables correctly, is it possible to do this with regex? if so how.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) please

Comment: @mescalinum Beat me to it.

Comment: But yes, in theory your table could have any number of tables inside of it, and those tables may have other unpredictable tags, which is a good example of why regex can't parse HTML.

Comment: k ty have to find another way to fetch this information then

Comment: `<table.*?><table.*?>(.*?)<\/table>.*<\/table>|<table.*?.*?>(.*?)<\/table>`, for example, may solve your issue, because its two tables, but it doesn't match three and so on, you can't write a robust solution that will work in all cases.

Comment: yes but was only giving a simple example have multiple tables tags inside not only one